# PHP -> MySQL not returning data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have confirmed that all of my code is working except for fetching of the array. It returns that there is only 1 row, and somehow 32 columns. However, my database has only 16 columns. Also when trying to print anything from the array out, there is nothing. Any help is much appreciated!

My query:

> SELECT * FROM information WHERE username='kmccmk9'

```
 //Get Acquired Data
$useradmin = $_GET['useradmin'];
$userpass = $_GET['userpass'];
$db = $_GET['db'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$sql = $_GET['sql'];

$link = mysql_connect("bondsolutionsnjcom.fatcowmysql.com", "aiforfrg", "********") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
$temp = "$"."username";
$sql = str_replace($temp,"'".$username."'",$sql);
$temp = "$"."password";
$sql = str_replace($temp,"'".$password."'",$sql);
echo $sql;

$result_id = mysql_query($sql) or die("DATABASE ERROR!".mysql_error());

echo count($result_id);

$total = mysql_num_rows($result_id);

if($total == 1) {
    $info = mysql_fetch_array($result_id);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($info);$i++) {
        echo $info[i]." ";
    }
} else {
    echo "something messed up";
}

mysql_close();
```

Using mysqli instead, my code looks like the following:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("bondsolutionsnjcom.fatcowmysql.com", $useradmin, $userpass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
$res->data_seek(0);
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo " id = " . $row['id'] . "\n";
}
```

But I am getting the following error and I don't know why:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function data_seek() on a non-object in
>   /hermes/waloraweb097/b516/moo.bondsolutionsnjcom/frg/scripts/executequery.php
>   on line 15

Comment: Try using mysqli_* functions or PDO, avoid using mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I'm now getting a strange error. Please see the edited post.

Comment: Can you post your sql query here?

Comment: echo $info[$i] /// you missed to declare $ for the variable i..

Comment: Thank you so much @Mahendra that fixed my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$useradmin = $_GET['useradmin'];
$userpass = $_GET['userpass'];
$db = $_GET['db'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$sql = $_GET['sql'];

$link = mysql_connect("bondsolutionsnjcom.fatcowmysql.com", "aiforfrg", "********") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
$temp = "$"."username";
$sql = str_replace($temp,"'".$username."'",$sql);
$temp = "$"."password";
$sql = str_replace($temp,"'".$password."'",$sql);
echo $sql;

$result_id = mysql_query($sql) or die("DATABASE ERROR!".mysql_error());

echo count($result_id);

$total = mysql_num_rows($result_id);

if ($total > 0) {
    $i=0;
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result_id))
    {
        echo $info[$i]." ";
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    echo "something messed up";
}

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this did not change anything.

Comment: put echo $info[$i]; check now

Comment: Yes the $i was part of the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. I have reviewed and changed your code:

```
//Get Acquired Data
$useradmin = $_GET['useradmin'];
$userpass = $_GET['userpass'];
$db = $_GET['db'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$sql = $_GET['sql'];

$link = mysql_connect("bondsolutionsnjcom.fatcowmysql.com", "aiforfrg", "********") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
$temp = "$"."username";
$sql = str_replace($temp,"'".$username."'",$sql);
$temp = "$"."password";
$sql = str_replace($temp,"'".$password."'",$sql);

$result_id = mysql_query($sql) or die("DATABASE ERROR!".mysql_error());

$total = mysql_num_rows($result_id);

if($total > 0) {
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_row($result_id)) {
        for ($i=0;$i<count($info);$i++) {
            echo $info[$i]." ";
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "something messed up";
}

 mysql_close();
```